CockroachDB configuration on NUMA enabled processors
Old CockroachDB documentation v2.1 has a cryptic description of CPUs with NUMA (Non-uniform Memory Access):

To add more processing power (up to 16 vCPUs), adding more vCPUs is
better than adding more RAM. Otherwise, add more nodes rather than
higher vCPUs will have
NUMA(non-uniform
memory access) implications. Our internal testing results indicate
this is the sweet spot for OLTP workloads. It is a best practice to
use uniform nodes so SQL performance is consistent.

But mention of NUMA has been removed from the later version of this document. Version 19.1 rephrased this as:

To optimize for throughput, use larger nodes, up to 32 vCPUs. Based on
internal testing results, 32 vCPUs is the sweet spot for OLTP
workloads. For RAM, aim for a ratio of 2 GB per vCPU.
To increase throughput further, add more nodes to the cluster instead
of increasing node size.

Cockroach Lab's Cloud Report in 2022 states:

Instances that have multiple NUMA nodes substantially under-perform
instances running on a single NUMA node for many workloads. For some
instance types, this accounted for the entire performance difference
between small and large instances.

There seems to be no general recommendations addressing NUMA architectures and how to configure Linux. I've heard CRDB is not NUMA-aware, but this is not documented.
RedHat has more specific advice:

Generally, best performance on NUMA systems is achieved by limiting
guest size to the amount of resources on a single NUMA node. Avoid
unnecessarily splitting resources across NUMA nodes.


Yeah, CRDB is not NUMA aware and has no way of avoiding splitting resource between nodes. I'm going to get report a documentation issue on the same page so that its clear.
